# Comparing SqlDataType to CLR nullable types in nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm writing tests to validate a mapping operation that take a fat heavy data object full of SqlDataTypes and converts them to pocos using simple CLR value types.

This is the method I've built thus far:

```
    private static void CompareValues(string k, Dictionary<string, string> propertyMap, TData sourceDal, TEntity entity)
    {
        string sourceField = k;
        string destField = propertyMap[k];
        object sourceval = sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).GetValue(sourceDal, null);
        object destval = entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).GetValue(entity, null);
        Assert.AreEqual(sourceval,
                        destval,
                        String.Format("Values not equal on fields {0} ({1}) to {2} ({3})",
                                      sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).Name, sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).PropertyType,
                                      entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).Name, entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).PropertyType)
            );

    }
```

Unfortunately, when comparing SqlInt32 to int?, this method fails the test.  The "value" of sourceval shows as `{74}` (a complex type with the usual extra SqlDataType properties), while the value of destval shows as `74`.

I do not want to make this method be type aware - I don't want it to assume that one side is a sql type and the other isn't - because my mapping tests will pass data in both directions.

I've tried extending CompareTo on SqlInt32

```
    public static int CompareTo(this SqlInt32 sqlInt32, int? value)
    public static int CompareTo(this SqlInt32 sqlInt32, int value)
```

but the extension methods aren't called (even though intelisense does detect them properly in my test project)

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  How do I set up a generic comparison between SqlDataTypes and CLR value types that yields accurate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very crude, not liking it at all, but turned out converting the vals to string works.

Still open to better suggestions, though.

```
    private static void CompareValues(string k, Dictionary<string, string> propertyMap, TData sourceDal, TEntity entity)
    {
        string sourceField = k;
        string destField = propertyMap[k];
        object sourceval = sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).GetValue(sourceDal, null);
        string sSource = sourceval.ToString();
        object destval = entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).GetValue(entity, null);
        string sDest = destval.ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(sSource,
                        sDest,
                        String.Format("Values not equal on fields {0} ({1}) to {2} ({3})",
                                      sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).Name, sourceDal.GetType().GetProperty(sourceField).PropertyType,
                                      entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).Name, entity.GetType().GetProperty(destField).PropertyType)
            );

    }
```